# Object locking in DB2 LUW

Tags: plsql, db2, procedure, isolation-level, locks

Working on object locking in IBM DB2 LUW, I am using Read stability (RS) level locking on my table. This locks the records I have fetched in the Select query ,unless I am done with the transaction and mention COMMIT explicitly and release the lock. During this process, with another query/procedure want to return the locked row for a different purpose. How to go about this?Also, there is a parameter WAIT_FOR_OUTCOME to set lock time, where do I define this timeout?

Comment: It would be good, if you provided more information about your locking and waiting statements. There are a lot of questions otherwise. Like readers don't block readers in db2 except you use 'with rs use and keep [update|exclusive] locks' clause in your locking select statement, so how do you get lock waits exactly? On which statements exactly? 'How to go about this' question should be more specific - where to go, what do you want to achieve? The 'wait for outcome' clause is not for setting lock timeout for a session, it's an instruction for CS (and not for RS) reader wait or not wait on lock.

Comment: Thank you. Let me tell you what I am trying to do. I have a procedure where I am trying to Insert in a table by selecting records from the same table and modifying some columns. I want to lock those source records while it being copied as someone from the application also might try to edit those records, thus I am using RS level lock by mentioning WITH RS after the select clause.

Comment: ..While this INSERT is in process, if someone from application(we have a UI and service calls) tries to edit that record, I want to send them the records that are locked, and release lock only after my procedure is done and records committed thus releasing the lock.

Comment: What does it mean - "I want to send them the records that are locked"? If you use `insert ... select ... with rs`, then these rows you read are already locked until the end of the transaction, and other session will not able to edit those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient information:  What is the effective setting for the CUR_COMMIT database?   Also, the locking behavior can change with specific Db2-registry settings which you have not mentioned such as DB2_SKIP_INSERTED , DB2_SKIP_DELETED among others etc.

If the effective value of the [CUR_COMMIT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0053556.html) database parameter is ON, and the other connection is using CS isolation for the query, then the other connection will get the currently committed value of a locked row (i.e. the writer is not blocking the reader).

If you wish you use wait for outcome, it is a clause applicable to a SELECT statement, refer to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000879.html).

Use a special register to have session-specific wait controls via
[SET CURRENT LOCK TIMEOUT WAIT n ;](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011874.html) (where n is the number of seconds), otherwise either a client-side timeout (if relevant),  or the database level LOCKTIMEOUT setting will apply, whichever is lower. Note that the default for [LOCKTIMEOUT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000329.html) is -1 (wait forever) which is nearly always unsuitable, typical values are 30 or 60 for OLTP.

Other connections can try using UR [isolation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0004121.html) per statement (e.g. for the query to select a locked row value).

Answer (score 0):

Up until v11.5.6, Db2 LUW did not allow to specify the lock wait timeout on the statement level. It had no SQL statement syntax for that.

With v11.5.6 or later you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   some_table
WHERE  col1 = 'Foo'
FOR READ ONLY
WITH RS USE AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS 
WAIT FOR OUTCOME WAIT 5
;
```

The above will create an exclusive row-level lock on the row(s) returned by the query. The new addition is the `WAIT 5` which means to wait 5 seconds for the lock, otherwise throw error.

Before v11.5.6 the lock timeout could only be specified at the session level or at the server level. Both of these are in [mao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53535765/1504556).

For more information:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statement-concurrent-access-resolution-clause